# Python 3.4 How do you limit user input

Tags: python

I have made a program which requires the user to go and come back after completing the command, I would like the user to press ENTER to then continue the programme, to do this I used a normal Input command that does not record the answer. However I would like it if the user cannot enter any text, the only thing they can do is press ENTER to proceed.

```
input("Please charge your device, when you are finished, press ENTER on the keyboard")
```

Comment: Please share your efforts, code example of what you've tried.

Comment: there is no standard command for this - you can try to find in internet `keypressed` or `getchar`, `getch`

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write an if loop that checks whatever the input is enter: For example:

```
import tty
import sys
import termios

orig_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)

tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
x = input("Text")
while x != chr(13): # Enter
    x=sys.stdin.read(1)[0]
    print("ERROR PLEASE TRY AGAIN")
    x = input("Text")

termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, orig_settings)
```

You might like to check this answer by @Turn at the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34497639/2080764

Comment: I don't want to find out how long it is, I don't want them to be able to enter anything at all. Only of course ENTER to continue.

Comment: When they get the option to input something I don't want a word or statement from them I just want them to press ENTER to continue.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood i'll fix my answer

Comment: I am on windows so I don't think this will work, but thanks anyways!