# Interrupting a timer with spacebar

Tags: python, macos, timer, sleep

Say I want to time how long I can hold my breath, and I want to do that with Python. I have  short script:

```
start = time()
try:
    while True: pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(time() - start)
```

This has the basic functionality I want, but it has an **fatal shortcoming**. After a long period of holding my breath, my mind might be a little fuzzy, and I might not find the coordination to hit Ctrl+c right away, and I might loose important data about my training.

The spacebar is much easier target to hit. Is there a simple way to make the loop stop when I press it?

EDIT: I'm on OSX

Comment: Lol... seriously? Just use a stopwatch.

Comment: fatal shortcoming....   Unlikely, you will pass out prior to dying.  You will only have a fatal shortcoming if you are doing it under water.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not seriously, but I would really like to be able to interrupt a loop with space bar rather than ctrl c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the console's keyboard (pty) driver into raw mode.
It is explained in this answer: [What is the easiest way to detect key presses in python 3 on a linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497323/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-detect-key-presses-in-python-3-on-a-linux-machine#34497639)

Quoting liberally from that answer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import termios
import time
import tty


def hold_breath(fin):
    orig_setting = termios.tcgetattr(fin)
    tty.setraw(fin)
    start = time.time()
    try:
        ch = fin.read(1)[0]
        assert ch == ' '
    finally:
        print('You lasted %.03f seconds.\r' % (time.time() - start))
        termios.tcsetattr(fin, termios.TCSADRAIN, orig_setting)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hit space.')
    hold_breath(sys.stdin)
```

Works fine on OS/X and Linux. If you wind up interrupting the program before it restores the original setting, then `$ stty sane` is your friend.

Comment: This looks promising, but link only answers should not be accepted on SE.

Comment: What does fin stand for, and why wouldn't I just use sys.stdin whenever needed when defining hold_breath?

Comment: Also, this solution does not allow me to have anything in the loop, as sys.stdin.read(1) freezes until a key is pressed. I cannot display a timer, say.

Comment: If you like sys.stdin, that's cool, stick with that. I commonly use fout & fin as file output and file input identifiers, and fin is just shorter here.

Comment: For non-blocking I/O, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your OS.  On Windows, this will stop on any key press, but you could look at the return value of `msvcrt.getch()` to determine if it was space.  Now when you pass out and your face hits the keyboard it will stop on any key.

```
import time
import msvcrt
start = time.time()
while not msvcrt.kbhit():  # Indicates a key is waiting to be read
    pass
end = time.time()
msvcrt.getch()  # read and (in this case) throw away the key press.
print(end-start)
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want... too bad I'm on MacOS. I should have specified in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys                                                                          
import termios                                                                      
import contextlib                                                                   

SPACE_BAR = 32                                                                      

@contextlib.contextmanager                                                       
def raw_mode(file):                                                                 
    old_attrs = termios.tcgetattr(file.fileno())                                    
    new_attrs = old_attrs[:]                                                        
    new_attrs[3] = new_attrs[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)                  
    try:                                                                            
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, new_attrs)              
        yield                                                                       
    finally:                                                                        
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, old_attrs)              


def main():                                                                         
    print 'exit with spacebar'                                                      
    with raw_mode(sys.stdin):                                                       
        try:                                                                        
            while True:                                                          
                if sys.stdin.read(1) == chr(SPACE_BAR):                          
                    break                                                        

        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):                                    
            pass                                                                 


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                       
    main()
```

Comment: I take your word for it but... THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY!